# How to disable cache management in android volley

Tags: android-volley

I m using android volley for load data from server to my app . But when i change data on server there is no change in app i.e it shows data from cache. How can i solve this ,please help me

Answer (score 0):

two way for this problem:

- remove `cache-control` header from server file (php or ...) `header('Cache-Control: no-cache');`

or

- `request.setShouldCache(false);`